# Still getting NotNullViolation despite belongs_to :foo, optional: true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a `has_one` and `belongs_to` association, like so:

```rb
# teacher.rb
has_one: :student
```

and

```rb
# student.rb 
belongs_to :teacher, optional: true
```

but when I try to create a student without a teacher...

```rb
a = Student.new()
a.save!
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "teacher_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Which doesn't make sense, since I have `optional: true`. I have tried `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed` numerous times but still the same error

Comment: what does your migration for the student table look like -- that's a DB error not a model validation error

Comment: @dbugger I am just really surprised the model doesn't take care of things, as AFAIK the docs say to simply add `optional: true` and all will be well. (I will check migration now)

Comment: The model takes care of the model.

Comment: @dbugger the students migration says `t.references :teacher, null: false, foreign_key: true`. Should I have edited that?

Comment: The `null: false` is the reason why you now get the error, as that makes your db column to not allow nulls. You will have to make a migration to set `null: true` for that column so it works as you expect it

Comment: The `optional` and its inverse `required` options for `belongs_to` just control if the association adds a `presence_of` validation. That really does not have anything to with a database driver error like this.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @dbugger and @Daniel Sindrestean and with help from another forum I see it's as simple as going into the existing migration file and changing `null: false` to `null: true`. Then remake the database. Or run a migration to change `null:true` if working on an existing app. Either way, `null: false` needs to be `null: true`

Also, from @max's comment:

> The `optional` and its inverse `required` options for `belongs_to` just control if the association adds a `presence_of` validation. That really does not have anything to with a database driver error